# How to provide different user pages with same login page for different users?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

what i am tryin to do is

i have common login page with 4 users each has  different roles
and i have a Singel master  pages where i have different contorls.....how to provide authentication to the  own page with the contorls assigned to them..regarding on thier role they should be directed to the given page....

```
       user 1 manager he needs only some controls on the page so when he logins the master page should contain only the controls assgned to him
```

applys the same for all users

can any one help me......planing ,i dont know where to start....

Comment: according to your requirement you need to add controls dynamically on master page ... build four different controls according to login and add to master page based on login role ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This in Button Click

```
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DebitCareBankApp;Data Source=SSDEV7-HP\\SQLEXPRESS");
        string cmdStr = "select LoginType from Login where UserName='" + TxtUserName.Text + "' AND Password = '" + TxtPassword.Text + "'";


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        con.Open();
        Object TypeUser = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        con.Close();

        if (TypeUser != null)
        {
            LblError.Visible = false;
            LblError.Text = "";
            if (TypeUser.ToString() == "Manager")
            {

                Response.Redirect("~//Administration/Manager/WorkManagement.aspx");
            }
            else if (TypeUser.ToString() == "HR")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~//Administration/Hr/CalculateAndGeneratePayslips.aspx");
            }
            else if (TypeUser.ToString() == "Employee")
            {
                Response.Redirect("~//Administration/CallingAgent/TodaysWork.aspx");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LblError.Visible = true;
            LblError.Text = "Invalid Credentials Entered, Try again";                
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way for this approach below are the steps you can follow

1. Keep one default Master Page // ("MasterPage.master")
2. Add as many master pages according to requirement // "manager.master/Admin.master"
3. Add the Pages to the default Master page
4. Add class file in **app_code** where u can map dynamic masterpage

Add this class in App_Code

```
public class DynamicPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            string masterfile = getMasterPageFromDatabase();
            if (!masterfile.Equals(string.Empty))
            {
                base.MasterPageFile = masterfile;
            }
            base.OnPreInit(e);
        }

        private string getMasterPageFromDatabase()
        {
            // check the conditions "manager.master/Admin.master"
            return "Admin.master";
        }
    }
```

when coming to .cs file for default.aspx.cs it would be "**System.Web.UI.Page**" replace that with **DynamicPage**

```
public partial class _Default : **System.Web.UI.Page**
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

finally it comes like

```
 public partial class _Default : **DynamicPage**
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

rest will happen automatically mapped

hope this helps !!!